# Get text from dynamically created EditText on click of a button

Tags: android, dynamic, android-edittext

I am creating a dynamic layout in which I have 2 EditText and one Button. On click of a button a new same king of layout is created. I want , when I click on the button I should be able to get data from edittexts and store them and then add new layout.I am not able to get data from edittext , it is coming up blank.
Below is my code . I am also adding screenshot of my layout [image: layout]

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
        ll_newView = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.ll_newView);
        scrollView = (ScrollView)findViewById(R.id.scrollView);
        bt_addView = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bt_addView);




        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        LinearLayout one = new LinearLayout(MainActivity2.this);


        //=====First EditText======//
        params.weight = 5.0f;
        params.setMargins(16,8,8,16);
        EditText  et_one = new EditText(MainActivity2.this);
        et_one.setPadding(10,10,10,10);
        et_one.setHint("Edit Text 1");
        et_one.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.edit_text_border));
        et_one.setLayoutParams(params);
        one.addView(et_one);

        //=====Second EditText======//
        EditText  et_two = new EditText(MainActivity2.this);
        et_two.setPadding(10,10,10,10);
        et_two.setHint("Edit Text 2");
        et_two.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.edit_text_border));
        et_two.setLayoutParams(params);
        one.addView(et_two);


        Button bt_plus = new Button(MainActivity2.this);
        bt_plus.setText("+");


        one.addView(bt_plus);


        ll_newView.addView(one);

        bt_plus.setOnClickListener(getOnClickDoSomething(et_one.getText().toString().trim(),et_two.getText().toString().trim()));


    }

    View.OnClickListener getOnClickDoSomething(final String one1,final String two1)  {
        return new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

                LinearLayout one = new LinearLayout(MainActivity2.this);
                Log.e("========","=====one ="+one1+"=========two = "+two1);
                //=====First EditText======//
                params.weight = 5.0f;
                params.setMargins(16,8,8,16);
                EditText  et_one = new EditText(MainActivity2.this);
                et_one.setPadding(10,10,10,10);
                et_one.setHint("Edit Text 1");
                et_one.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.edit_text_border));
                et_one.setLayoutParams(params);
                one.addView(et_one);

                //=====Second EditText======//
                EditText  et_two = new EditText(MainActivity2.this);
                et_two.setPadding(10,10,10,10);
                et_two.setHint("Edit Text 2");
                et_two.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.edit_text_border));
                et_two.setLayoutParams(params);
                one.addView(et_two);


                Button bt_plus = new Button(MainActivity2.this);
                bt_plus.setText("+");

                one.addView(bt_plus);



                ll_newView.addView(one);

                bt_plus.setOnClickListener(getOnClickDoSomething(et_one.getText().toString().trim(),et_two.getText().toString().trim()));
                Log.e("========","=====one ="+et_one.getText().toString().trim()+"=========two = "+ et_two.getText().toString().trim());

            }
        };
    }
```

Comment: can you post your code how you creating dynamically two edittext and button,i also want to create same pattern.

Comment: I have already added my code, I am creating one layout by default in on create and then on button click I am creating other layouts.

Comment: I got it.thank you@Paras Watts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing to the `getOnClickDoSomething` function the text of the newly created editText, so understandably it will be blank. What you may want is to change `getOnClickDoSomething`, so that it accepts reference to the editTexts themselves, and later you can retrieve the their current text. (You will have to be careful not to leak views, as you have anonymous classes holding on to the Views.)
Example: Just change the following lines as follows

```
bt_plus.setOnClickListener(getOnClickDoSomething(et_one, et_two)); }


View.OnClickListener getOnClickDoSomething(final EditText one1,final EditText two1) 


Log.e("========","=====one ="+one1.getText().toString().trim(),+"=========two = "+two1.getText().toString().trim());
```

Comment: Can you add a small example ?