# single onclick listener for multiple textviews created programmatically in Android

Tags: android, view, onclicklistener, textview

So I have successfully created a number of textviews programmatically using the below piece of code that I have written. I would like to create an efficient single listener for these textviews as I need to perform an action on click. How do I know which textview was tapped on and attach a listener to it programmatically?

PS: Please don't post solutions using XML layouts file. Thanks in advance.

```
optionCubesTextviews = new TextView[cubesLength];
    for(i=0;i<cubesLength;i++) {
        optionCubesTextviews[i] = new TextView(this);
        optionCubesTextviews[i].setId(View.generateViewId());
        optionCubesTextviews[i].setTextSize(baseFont);
        final RelativeLayout.LayoutParams optionCubesTextviewsParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        optionCubesTextviewsParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, solutionCubeTextviews[i].getId());
        if (i != 0) {
            optionCubesTextviewsParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, optionCubesTextviews[i - 1].getId());
        }
        optionCubesTextviewsParams.setMargins(10, 10, 10, 10);
        optionCubesTextviews[i].setPadding(20, 20, 20, 20);
        optionCubesTextviews[i].setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT);
        //String qTextColorColor = preferenceFile.getString("qTextColor", DefaultManager.qTextColor);
        optionCubesTextviews[i].setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        optionCubesTextviews[i].setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(randomColorString));
        optionCubesTextviews[i].setText(Character.toString(shuffledAnswerAsOptions.charAt(i)));
        optionCubesTextviews[i].setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        //Adding to Layout in invisible state
        rLayout.addView(optionCubesTextviews[i], optionCubesTextviewsParams);
    }
```

Comment: implement onclicklistner then set  optionCubesTextviews.setOnclicklistner(this);  and put your common code in Onclick method which one you use for all textview .

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46108600/get-text-from-dynamically-created-edittext-on-click-of-a-button refer this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just create a listener and assign it to your views like you would any other attribute.

```
OnClickListener l = new OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View v){
        // TODO whatever...
    }
}

for(i=0 ; i < optionCubesTextviews.length; i++) {
    optionCubesTextviews[i].setTag(i);
    optionCubesTextviews[i].setOnClickListener(l);
}
```

Comment: how will i know which textview is tapped?

Comment: Set position as tag to TextView like optionCubesTextviews[i].setTag(i);

Comment: If you want to do different things, just use different listeners.

Comment: I was thinking about that. But is it worth adding 15 listeners? doesnt seem efficient clean code to me

Comment: Depends how different your actions are.

Comment: And, if you're worried about Object allocations, setTag will either box an int into an Integer or create a WeakHashMap and then an Integer depending on the version you use.

Answer (score 0):

Check this example i made and I hope it helps you :)

In this way you can check which view clicked.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

  // THIS IS MY MAIN LAYOUT
    LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_layout);

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        TextView textView = new TextView(this);
        textView.setTag(String.valueOf(i));
        textView.setOnClickListener(this);
        textView.setText("TEXT VIEW " + i);
        linearLayout.addView(textView);
    }
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getTag().toString()) {
        case "0":
            Toast.makeText(this, "TEXT VIEW 1", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            break;
        case "1":
            Toast.makeText(this, "TEXT VIEW 2", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            break;
        case "2":
            Toast.makeText(this, "TEXT VIEW 3", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            break;
        default:
            Toast.makeText(this, "Default", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}}
```