# Same OnClickListener for 9 different TextViews

Tags: android, textview, onclicklistener

I have the following 9 TextViews:

```
TextView option1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.option1);
TextView option2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.option2);
TextView option3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.option3);
TextView option4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.option4);
TextView option5 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.option5);
TextView option6 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.option6);
TextView option7 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.option7);
TextView option8 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.option8);
TextView option9 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.option9);
```

And all of them will do the exact same thing when clicked. Basically I want for each TextView clicked to get it's text and show a Toast with that text (for now).

I have set the click listener for option 1 but there must be a way of creating a reusable function out of this rather than duplicating the code for each TextView...

```
option1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        mSelectedOption = option1.getText().toString();
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, mSelectedOption, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

Comment: Assign `new View.OnClickListener() { ... }` to a variable and then use that 9 times. `listener = new View.OnClickListener() ... option1.setOnClickListener(listener)`.

Comment: That makes your listener reusable (for TextViews): `selectedText = ((TextView)v).getText()`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [single onclick listener for multiple textviews created programmatically in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46708473/single-onclick-listener-for-multiple-textviews-created-programmatically-in-andro)

Comment: You might consider having a `RecyclerView` instead of having 9 different buttons.

Comment: you can initialize the textviews or any views using this lib http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/ its great when you have multiple components ....iknow my answer not you want..but from your question i understand you need better and fast way @Alin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this for your TextViews:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        button1.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
        button2.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
        button3.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
}

private OnClickListener onClickListener = new OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
         switch(v.getId()){
             case R.id.button1:
                  //DO something
             break;
             case R.id.button2:
                  //DO something
             break;
             case R.id.button3:
                  //DO something
             break;
         }

   }
};
```

I understand that you are not using buttons, but just replace the button information with the TextView names.

You can also define all the click listeners for the Text View inside your xml file like so:

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="textViewOnClick"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Random TextView" />
```

Then you can create a method called textViewOnClick which uses the switch statement:

```
public void buttonOnClick(View view)
{
 switch(view.getId())
 {
  case R.id.button1:
  // Code for button 1 click
  break;

  case R.id.button2:
  // Code for button 2 click
  break;

  case R.id.button3:
  // Code for button 3 click
  break;
 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it's not what I need. It will still be a big chunk of mostly duplicated code. I simply want to minimize the code and make it more efficient and reusable.

Comment: Well this actually reduces the code because you're condensing it down to one method onClickListener() with multiple switch statements versus doing it the other way is which is defining 9 different onClick methods doing the same thing

Comment: The only way to make it shorter would be to make an array of your buttons/textviews and loop through the array to assign the listeners.

Comment: @Alin I added another solution to my answer just now

Comment: Your answer kinda gave me an idea. Using the switch statement with a custom function will work fine if I just pass the id from each case to use in the function. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for a `switch` statement. You can just use a `Map` of resource ids to `TextView`s:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final int[] IDS = {
        R.id.option1, R.id.option2, R.id.option3, R.id.option4, R.id.option5, R.id.option6, R.id.option7, R.id.option8, R.id.option9
    };

    private View.OnClickListener onClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mSelectedOption = mOptions.get(v.getId()).getText().toString();
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, mSelectedOption, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    };

    private final Map<Integer, TextView> mOptions = new HashMap();

    private String mSelectedOption;

    private void initOptions() {
        for (int id : IDS ) {
            TextView option = (TextView) findViewById(id);
            option.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
            mOptions.put(id, option);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        .
        .
        .
        initOptions();
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks you for your answer. I will try this in a couple of hours. It does look a lot cleaner than using switch statements.

Answer (score 0):

You can get all views from root view

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    View v = findViewById(R.id.root);
    for(int index = 0; index<((ViewGroup)v).getChildCount(); ++index) {
        View nextChild = ((ViewGroup)v).getChildAt(index);
        nextChild.setOnClickListener(listener);
    }
}

View.OnClickListener listener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.id1:{

            }
            case R.id.id2:{

            }

        }
    }
};
```

}

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/root"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="vb.com.broadcaster.MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/id1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/id2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```